# How Can I save a javascript map object to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to get my map object as

```
Map(3) {'2a820899-844f-4fe1-bec6-e4c348920485' => 'Yes', 'c30102dc-ffe8-4a3f-9498-59625d9981c4' => 'Me is me', '5b44fe6a-2453-43f9-bf1b-3c3adc51cc96' => 'Yes'}
```

when I log it to the console. but when I send it to the backend, I get an empty object. How do i fix this?

```
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState(new Map())

  function updateAnswer(id, value) {
    const newMap = new Map(answers)
    newMap.set(id, value)
    setAnswers(newMap)
  }

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(answers)
    await createAnswers(name, phone, email, city, answers)
  }
```

on the console, I get the above data. But when I save it, I gt an empty object

```
export const createAnswers = (name, phone, email, city, answers) => {
  return request('/v1/answers', {
    data: {
      name,
      phone,
      email,
      city,
      answers,
    },

    method: 'POST',
  })
}
```

Comment: post your createAnswers function

Comment: added the createAnswers function

Comment: can you also add the answers api endpoint? this needs more info. also any errors thrown

Comment: I would guess your api is expecting an object not a Map, and that when it's encoded in the post body it is sent as an empty object.

Comment: how may i convert it to an object?

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(answers.entries());`